# Why does adding a true statement make this line give an error?

Tags: excel-formula

Why does =MAX(IF(N:N<R2;N:N;"FALSE")) give me a result,
But =MAX(IF(AND(N:N<R2;1=1);N:N;"FALSE")) give me #VALUE! Error?

How come when I add another true statement it becomes an error?

Comment: What do you expect `IF(N:N<R2;N:N;"FALSE")` to acutually do? How do you compare a range `N:N` to a single cell `R2`?

Comment: `=IF(N:N<R2;N:N;"FALSE")` will return the text `"FALSE"` if the condition is not met. The text is not the same as a value. Dropping the quotation mark will return `FALSE` as a value, which is translated to `0`: `MAX(IF(N:N<R2;N:N;FALSE))`, but since `IF` defaults to TRUE and FALSE anyway you could choose not to mention FALSE at all: `MAX(IF(N:N<R2;N:N))`

Comment: The first statement goes through a list of numbers and returns the highest value that is smaller than R2.

Comment: The second statement is basically the same just with an added condition that is always true. Thats why i dont understand why the first one works fine, but the second one gives an error?